# How to split text based on a string?

Tags: bash

I have a text string here:

> lorem ipsum dolor: sit amet

and i want to split it into 2 variables: col1 and col2 based on string "dolor:" delimiter.

col1 is assigned with the first string:

> lorem ipsum dolor:

and col2 is assigned with the second string:

> sit amet

how do i do that from the terminal?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I split a string on a delimiter in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918886/how-do-i-split-a-string-on-a-delimiter-in-bash)

Comment: not really. I need to do it interactively in the terminal. But i learned from that as well. Thanks bro

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bash makes things simple with parameter expansions that allow trimming from the front (beginning) or back (end) of a string. For example:

```
s="lorem ipsum dolor: sit amet"  ## full string
b="${s##*dolor: }"               ## remove everything from front through "dolor: "
a="${s% $b}"                     ## remove everything saved in $b from back + space
```

Example:

```
s="lorem ipsum dolor: sit amet"
b="${s##*dolor: }"
a="${s% $b}"
printf "a: %s\nb: %s\n" "$a" "$b"
a: lorem ipsum dolor:
b: sit amet
```

Where `$a` and `$b` contain the desired strings. The parameter expansions can be found in `man bash` but the ones to trim from front or back are summarized as:

```
${var#pattern}      Strip shortest match of pattern from front of $var
${var##pattern}     Strip longest match of pattern from front of $var
${var%pattern}      Strip shortest match of pattern from back of $var
${var%%pattern}     Strip longest match of pattern from back of $var
```

(**note:** pattern can contain the normal globbing characters such as `'*'`)

Let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: My God. that is all? here i am fiddling with grep and what not. thanks

Comment: *Parameter Expansions* are mighty powerful text processing tools in bash. Best part about it -- they are built-in and no additional subshells are spawned. Makes them safe to use in a loop. Good luck with your scripting !

Comment: If you really wanted to torment yourself, you could split the string with `awk` into two separate lines and then set `$IFS` to split on newlines and feed both strings into an array. It gets ugly quick. If you just want to test the split with `awk` you can use `awk -F: '{print $1":\n"substr($2,2)}' <<< "lorem ipsum dolor: sit amet"` -- but again that will spawn an unnecessary subshell `:)`

Comment: You can use a second form of expansion (*parameter expansion with substring replacement*) to do the same thing -- but unlike substring removal, these are not POSIX compliant, `a="${s/:*/}:"` and `b="${s/*: /}"` will do the same thing. Basically the expansion is `${var/pattern/replace}` to replace the 1st occurrence of pattern or `${var//pattern/replace}` to replace all occurrences. In the examples the `replace` part is empty which just removes `pattern`. (you can omit the `'/'` before an empty pattern and replace is taken as empty)